# Backup and recovery of Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

The cassandra cluster has 4 nodes and replication factor is 3.The read and write consitency is set to local_Quoram.

Any pointers on backup and restore procedure of cassandra cluster ,As i am very new to it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodetool snapshot. It will create a snapshot of the data, then copy snapshot to a safe storage and whenever you want to restore copy back the data to node and restore it.
More details here
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html